# "unrecognized selector sent to class" crash when trying to share code throughout an Xcode Workspace

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, workspace, search-path

Steps to reproduce:

Create a new Xcode Workspace (WorkspaceTest).

Create a single-view project called "One".

In the workspace (not the project), create a Group called "Shared". In that folder create a category called UIColor+Hex:

.h:

```
@interface UIColor (Hex)

+ (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString*)hexString;

@end
```

.m:

```
@implementation UIColor (Hex)


+ (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)hexString {
   //implementation here
}

@end
```

Go to the "One" Target Build Settings and add this for Header Search Paths:

```
/Users/me/iOS/test/WorkspaceTest/Shared
```

Go to the default ViewController.h and add this:

```
#import "UIColor+Hex.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];        
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"ff0000"];
}
```

The project compiles fine, which means it found UIColor+Hex.h.

However when it runs I get this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIColor colorWithHexString:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x107db8c60
```

This method is present in the UIColor+Hex.m file. What else do I need to do?

Comment: Is the .m file being built and included in your app?

Comment: Um, apparently not. The question is how to include it.

Comment: I forget the details (been awhile since I did this, and don't have a mac at hand), but basically RMB on the file, select it's properties, and check your project in the list of build targets.

Comment: That's if the file is already in the Project. This is the case of a shared group of files that does not belong to any single project. Like I said above, it's created in the workspace, not in the project. I want it to be available to all projects in the Workspace. There's no "Target Membership" option for files that are not in a project.

Comment: You've got to add it to the project.  I can't tell you the details.  (No, maybe I can.  Add a "Shared" folder to the left-hand file list, RMB on that, and select "Add files" or some such.)

Comment: The point is to make a set of files that are shared between all projects in the workspace. Like a static library, but without the pain of creating and maintaining a static library.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can add a file without physically moving it into the project directories.  Otherwise you need something like CocoaPods, but that's taking on some of that "pain".